# What happens in Tokio's run_queue when you call the standard library's channel recv or try_recv methods?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm not sure what would happen if you used the [standard library's channel implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html) in the following cases.

## Case 1

```
let (tx, rx) = std::sync::mpsc::unbounded_channel();

// some code where multiple producers are sending data through tx
tokio::spawn(async move {
    while let Some(message) = rx.recv().await {
        //do something with message
    }
})
```

## Case 2

```
let (tx, rx) = std::sync::mpsc::unbounded_channel();

// some code where multiple producers are sending data through tx
tokio::spawn(async move {
    while let Some(message) = rx.try_recv().await {
        //do something with message }
    }
})
```

In both cases when the channel is empty and the receivers are waiting for some messages, will the Tokio task in case 1 stay in the `run_queue` since `recv()` is blocking?

On the other hand, since `try_recv()` is not blocking, will the Tokio task get off the run queue so that threads can do other task when there are no messages to read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into source code, my conclusion is that when Tokio channels are waiting for the messages, they are moved off the run queue. Calling `recv()` on the receiver will never be a blocking code when using Tokio.

I also had doubt whether `futures::stream::stream::poll_next()` would be blocking, but as with Tokio channels, they are awakened when some value is available.